# Position nested list next to parent list with CSS

Tags: css, list, position

i have got a nested list, which is positioned under the parent list:

```
<ul>
  <li> Item 1 </li>
  <ul>
    <li> Subitem 1 </li>
    <li> Subitem 2 </li>
    <li> Subitem 3 </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to style them with css so that the nested list is right and centered to the parent list? The result should look like this:

```
          - Subitem 1
Item 1    - Subitem 2  
          - Subitem 3
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tabular approach:

```css
.list {
  display: table;
}
.list > li, .list > ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Subitem 1</li>
    <li>Subitem 2</li>
    <li>Subitem 3</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

However, note that the HTML above is invalid, because the inner `ul` should be a child of `li`.

With a correct layout, I would use an `inline-block` approach:

```css
.list > li > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
      <li>Subitem 2</li>
      <li>Subitem 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```